# Redirect with React Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, react-router

I am in need of help, I am coding this form and after I submit it, the state for "posted" changes from false to true and I would expect "return Redirect to="/landing" ;" to redirect me to the landing page, however, it doesn't which I assume is because the line doesn't re-run after the initial render. I was hoping that changing the state of "posted" would cause a re-render. I have heard about using history push and tried to adapt it to my code yet I failed. I don't know how to wrap my component with "withRouter" given that I have it already wrapped with "connect". How can I achieve this? I have read numerous posts about this yet I can't figure how to adapt it to my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { createProject } from "../actions/projectAction";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { push } from "connected-react-router";

const EditProject = ({ posted, createProject }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    projectTitle: "",
    projectDescription: "",
    deliveryDate: ""
  });

  const { projectTitle, projectDescription, deliveryDate } = formData;

  const onChange = e => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProject({ projectTitle, projectDescription, deliveryDate });
    dispatch(push("/login"));
  };

  if (posted) {
    return <Redirect to="/landing" />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <h4>Project Title</h4>
          <input
            name="projectTitle"
            value={projectTitle}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Your project title"
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <h4>Delivery Date</h4>
          <input
            type="date"
            className="form-control"
            name="deliveryDate"
            value={deliveryDate}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <h4>Description</h4>
          <textarea
            name="projectDescription"
            value={projectDescription}
            className="form-control"
            rows="10"
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          ></textarea>
          <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
          <a href="/projects" className="btn btn-danger">
            Cancel
          </a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

EditProject.propTypes = {
  createProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posted: state.posted
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProject })(EditProject);
```

Comment: This code should work. Did you check that the value of `posted` is as expected? (e.g. `console.log('posted', posted)` just above the `if`) If it's true, the problem would be in the way how router is initialized (e.g. a typo in `<Route path="/lnding">`). If not, the problem is most likely in redux (e.g. the reducer not setting `state.posted` correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to define your route. From my following code you can get a little bit idea of the routing.

In **`App.js`** basically I defined the routes and I have created two more functional components **`Landing`** and **`EditProject`** to simulate your idea. Moreover I have used **`Link`** for navigation purpose

**`App.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import EditProject from "./editProject";
import Landing from "./landing";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div id="container">
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Landing Page</Link>
            <Link to="/editproject">Edit Project</Link>
          </div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/editproject" component={EditProject} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**`Landing`** functional component

```
import React from "react";

const Landing = () => {
  return <h1>Landing Page</h1>;
};

export default Landing;
```

**`EditProject`** functional component

```
import React from "react";

const EditProject = props => {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");
    //do your task here before redirect
    //...
    props.history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Edit Project</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditProject;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I did a similar implementation as yours and now I can redirect after I submit form!

Comment: Ok if my answer helps you or if you think this answer may help others too, kindly make it tick and upvote to reach this answer to other people

Comment: Hi @tareqaziz How to get functional component state value on router

Answer (score 0):

There're two things I would like to address in your code.

if `EditProject` component is going straight to `Route` then you have access to push.

```
const EditProject = ({ { posted, createProject, history: { push } }) => {
    push() // your access to push
}
```

secondly, In your connect, I don't support that idea of your connect. Probably, the submit function wasn't running.

You can do something like below to make a difference.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { handleNewProject, createProject })(EditProject);
```

Now, to Re-write `EditProject` component would be

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const EditProject = ({ { posted, handleNewProject, history: { push } }) => {
    push() // your access to push
    // useEffect React component life cycle Hook
    useEffect(() => () => push('/landing'), [posted]);

}
```

Notice I use [React Hook](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/hooks/) just like the way you would use `React class component` [life circle](https://blog.logrocket.com/frustrations-with-react-hooks/).

Answer (score 0):

Say, on Logout submit button, I want to goto user/login page:

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {    
    // ...

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        props.history.push('/user/login');
    }
}
```

NOTE: if `props` is not present in the component argument, you can add it.

---

Some other non-standard ways in react.js (but commonly used in large projects)

One of the below will work:

```
let url = '/user/login'

props.history.push(url);

window.location = url;
window.location.href = url;
window.location.replace(url);

window.open(url)
window.open(url, "_self")
window.open(url, '_blank');
window.open(url, 'newWindow');
window.open(url, 'newwin');

window.location.reload(true);
```

---

Comment: should this be it? props is an empty object for me

Comment: Sure, please see the above answer, you can either add `props` OR use one of the `window.` methods, see updated answer above.

Comment: for me it worked by importing `import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'` and then I declared `const history = useHistory();` and then I could use it in the jsx `history.push('/some-page');`

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo cool, happy to know a similar one worked.